# How to readline in Haskell without transfer to the next line?

Tags: haskell, io, console, readline

I am trying to use readline in Haskell without transfer cursor to the next line.

For example, I wrote the following code:

```
readEvalPrintLoop :: IO()
readEvalPrintLoop = do
    line <- getLine
    case line of
            "bye" -> return ()
            line   -> do putStrLn $ interpret line
                         readEvalPrintLoop
```

After starting the program:

```
> 1 2 + . <enter>
3
```

But I want **to find the easiest way to get follow**:

```
> 1 2 + . <enter> 3
```

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, it should be the input buffering as you mention. Note that this buffer is not present in the Haskell application but rather in the terminal (either in the OS kernel or in a terminal emulator). By default, a terminal echoes each key and moves the cursor as usual, without any interaction with the application. An application can ask the terminal to change this default behavior, and indeed ncurses is a common way to do that.

Comment: @Bakuriu Buffering is only tangentially related: the real problem here is echoing. In my answer I *also* turn off buffering, but not to prevent the newline from appearing; rather, it is to allow everything else to appear at once rather than at buffer-sized chunks!

Comment: @Andrei If you're like me, this problem might have caused you to wonder exactly what's going on and what behaviors are configurable. You can read a lot more about it at [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/), though I warn you: if you just want to Get Things Done, this is going to be way more information than you wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press enter -- as when you press any other key -- it is printed to the screen. You can turn off this behavior with [`hSetEcho`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetEcho):

```
main = do
    hSetEcho stdin False
    readEvalPrintLoop
```

However, if you do so, you will find this has some collateral damage: the enter is no longer echoed, but neither is anything else you type, so it looks like everything you enter is invisible! You can fix this by implementing your modified echo strategy manually. You will need to do two things: set the input stream to an unbuffered mode with [`hSetBuffering`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering) (so that you receive input immediately, rather than at end-of-line) and print each non-enter character you receive. So:

```
myGetLine :: IO String
myGetLine = do
    c <- getChar
    case c of
        '\n' -> return "" -- don't echo newlines
        _ -> do
            putChar c -- do echo everything else
            fmap (c:) myGetLine

readEvalPrintLoop :: IO()
readEvalPrintLoop = do
    line <- myGetLine -- getLine changed to myGetLine
    case line of
            "bye" -> return ()
            line   -> do putStrLn $ interpret line
                         readEvalPrintLoop

main = do
    hSetEcho stdin False
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    readEvalPrintLoop
```

Comment: N.B. Depending on what behavior you want, you may want to check for EOF in `myGetLine`.